# split string for specific column

Tags: regex, r, split

I have a file like this:

```
       V1                                               V2
1 1-500891               CGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACCCGCTGAA
2 2-280976                           AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
3 3-223181                           TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
```

I would like to split (and swap) the V1 column resulting in the following output

```
                                       Sequence    Count
           CGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACCCGCTGAA      500891
                       AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC      280976 
                       TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA      223181
```

I have tried this, but it did not work:

```
df_split <- strsplit(as.character(df), split="-", fixed=T)
```

Comment: To swap the two columns you can do `df <- df[c(2,1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `sub` to remove the part of the string up till `-`.

```
df$V1 <- sub('.*-', '', df$V1)
df
#     V1                                 V2
#1 500891 CGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACCCGCTGAA
#2 280976             AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
#3 223181             TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
```

You applied the `strsplit` on the whole dataset instead of specific column ("V1").  Here, is a possible option for you to consider

```
df$V1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$V1),
                    split="-", fixed=TRUE),`[`,2)
df$V1
#[1] "500891" "280976" "223181"
```

Or an option using `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, 'V1', 'Count', '.*-(.*)')
 #  Count                                 V2
 #1 500891 CGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACCCGCTGAA
 #2 280976             AGGTTCCGGATAAGTAAGAGCC
 #3 223181             TCTTAACCCGGACCAGAAACTA
```